# convert Date to DD-MMM-YY in redshift

Tags: sql, date, amazon-redshift

I have a requirement to convert the `yyyy-MM-dd` date format into `DD-MMM-YY`.

e.g.: `2018-06-14 -> 14-JUN-18.`

I tried `to_char(date,'DD-MMM-YY')`, however it's resulting in `14-06M-18`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [format mask](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_FORMAT_strings.html) for the three letter month abbreviation in all caps is `MON`, not `MMM`:

```
to_char(date, 'DD-MON-YY')
```

Maybe you are coming from another API/language where `MMM` would have worked in that case.

Comment: This returns a VARCHAR type. I want to return a date type only. Is that possible?

Comment: @Sanchay The whole point of using `to_char` is to take a date and generate some sort of string output based on that date.  If you already have a date, then I don't understand your question.  You don't need to be concerned with the internal format of a date in your table.

Comment: So the thing is we interpret the output 2 ways. At one place, it used as a date, so any format works. In the second case, we interpret it as a String. Thus this compex usecase. The date of redshift by default outputs YYYY-MM-DD, we however want to return date, whose toString is essentially dd-MMM-yyyy

Comment: Then I don't see the issue here.  If you want a string formatted a certain way, then use `to_char`.  Otherwise, you may use your date as-is.